# I recreated my root partition using fdisk (resized it), but now the filesystem is corrupt

Tags: partitioning, root, fdisk

I was under the impression that i could resize my root partition, recreate it using fdisk but only larger. And then reboot, and do an online filesystem resize with resize2fs. however, that doesn´t seem to be the case. Now i can´t mount my partition that is running ext4.

Any suggestions on how i should proceed on recovering the partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do it on a live filesystem. I cross my fingers that using fdisk on a live partition did not completely damage it. Always perform such operations from the system booted from LiveCD / rescue CD / other partition. Partition may not be writeable during that operation.

Do not jump to my instructions immediately; maybe someone will come up with a better plan. I include these instructions just in case no one else responds.

Start the system using LiveCD and go to rescue mode. Resize the partition as planned using resize2fs. Try to mount the resized partition and see whether it works. If you have anything valuable (i.e., other than OS / software), back it up immediately. If everything went OK, try to reboot.

Comment: Solved my issues by running partedmagic from a usb stick. and using the utilites testdisk (to recover my partitions), and parted to redo partitioning properly.

Comment: I suggest that you answer your own question describing in detail what you did, it might be interesting for other users.